# How to connect a domain to XAMPP

Tags: html, server, xampp, ip, domain-name

Ok, so I have an ip that works, I bought a domain name as well, how do I configure it so that when I type the domain it points to the ip, I do not want some kind of masked url forwarding as I want you to be able to type for example /img/ and go to that directory.
Any help?

(Edit: Spelling)

Comment: Can you give more details about your hosting setup? What do you mean when you say you "have an IP?"

Comment: So, I have successfully setup XAMPP and I can access my website from another device on another network using the IP. I want to be able to use my domain name with it without url forwarding.

Comment: Your question is rather broad. How you configure the DNS to point a domain name at an IP address usually depends on the user interface provided by the company you bought the domain name from. How you configure Apache HTTPD to recognise the domain depends on if you want it to serve up one website or switch between different ones depending on the domain name.

Answer (score -1):

May I know what's domain vendor you subscribe, like Godaddy?

You can add the A record which can point to your IP address.

Go to 'Manage DNS' and find existing A record or add an A record,

here is a reference guide like Godaddy:

https://hk.godaddy.com/help/a-19238?lang=en

Comment: I tried using an A record but I essentially want to park the domain, not redirect

Comment: Do you setup it cpanel or webadmin?